# Finding a channel based on selfprovided data in c# getstream-io

Tags: c#, getstream-io

To find certain channels we put extra metadata in the channel (genericData)
This is done by our backend with the following piece of code

```cs
var data = new GenericData();
data.SetData("assignmentId", 123);
var channel = GetChannel(channelId, data);
```

Next we try to retrieve all channels where this is true.

```cs
var filterDict = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "assignmentId", new int[] { 123 } }
};

var query = await this.streamChatClient.QueryChannels(new QueryChannelsOptions().WithFilter(filterDict));
```

Expectation:
We created a channel with assignmentID = 123, 
with this call we want to retrieve all channels where this is set in the genericData.

Result:
We got count[0] the channel exists.

Is the additional data query-able? If so, is our syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to build your query with this kind of Dictionary structure?

```
{
  "assignmentId": {
    "$eq": 123
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work server side, but not client side. We'll dive further into it.